# python2.7--TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not str

Tags: python, typeerror, raise

**following code in python 2.7.10**

```
def inputnumber() :
    x = input('pick a number : ')
    if x == 17 :
        raise 'BadNumberError' , '17 is a bad number'
    return x
```

**and when i run this , it gives me TypeError :**

***TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from        BaseException, not str***

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that this is not how exceptions are raised in Python. You `raise` an object that is derived from `BaseException` (generally it is derived from one of the [built-in exception types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html). So, your example would be retooled like this:

```
class BadNumberError(ValueError):
    pass

def inputnumber():
    x = input('Pick a number: ')
    if x == 17:
        raise BadNumberError('17 is a bad number')

    return x
```

The results being:

```
[/home/.../Python/demos]$ python2.7 exception_demo.py 
Pick a number: 17
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exception_demo.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(inputnumber())
  File "exception_demo.py", line 7, in inputnumber
    raise BadNumberError('17 is a bad number')
__main__.BadNumberError: 17 is a bad number
[/home/.../Python/demos]$ python2.7 exception_demo.py 
Pick a number: 18
18
```

One thing to note is that it is *extremely* common to see people just using instances of the built-in exception types directly, like this:

```
def inputnumber():
    x = input('Pick a number: ')
    if x == 17:
        raise ValueError('17 is a bad number')

    return x
```

It's presumably more convenient, though I personally don't love it, since it makes it difficult to catch exceptions caused by specific conditions.